# is it possible to do selective 301 wildcard redirects in iis7 with C#

Tags: c#, .htaccess, redirect, iis-7, http-status-code-301

**Example:**

- -www.google.com/maps/
  -www.google.com/
  -www.google.com/mail/

For the above url lists, I want to do wildcard 301 redirects for all the url with http://www.google.com/ but not the one with http://www.google.com/maps/

htaccess type or c# logic? possible?

Comment: Is it possible to do wildcard 301 redirects that matches and avoids

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use .htacceess on IIS unless you have some module installed.

Comment: WebServer IIS-7 on win2k8 and I know how to use .htaccess on IIS by using urlwriter?? module or embedding them in the servers settings file in inetsrv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem was solved by adding/using Url Rewrite Module on IIS and creating a incoming rule using RegX and server URL variables